# При продаже камней, нужно чтобы за это давались деньги. Когда использую команду камни исчезают, а деньги не прибавляются

Tags: javascript, discord-api

```
if(msg.content.toLowerCase() == '!sellore') {
        if(u.ore < 1000) {
            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed ()
                .setTitle('Продажа Камней')
                .setColor('#fd9090')
                .setDescription('Это слишком мало, тебе необходимо иметь минимум 1000 <:ore:699333135959195670>. Как надолбишь их, приходи.')
                .setFooter('Если у вас появилась проблема !report суть подачи репорта')
            msg.channel.send(embed)
        }
        if(u.ore >= 1000) {
            var sum_add = u.money * 1250;
            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed ()
                    .setTitle('Продажа Камней')
                    .setDescription('Вы продали ' + u.ore + ' <:ore:699333135959195670> и получили ' + sum_add + ' ')
                    .setColor('#fd9090')
            u.money += sum_add;
            u.ore-=u.ore;
            msg.channel.send(embed)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Проклятая обдираловка!

Comment: какие камни, куда продажа?

Comment: `var sum_add = u.money * 1250;` это не ясно, если `u.money == 0`, то и `sum_add` тоже будет 0. `u.ore >= 1000` и `u.ore-=u.ore;` как понимать? Количество камней обнуляется вне зависимости оттого сколько их? Лишь бы больше 1000? А денег всегда в 1250 раз больше, а если их нет?

Answer (score 0):

Я так подозреваю, что должно быть:

```
let sum_add = u.ore * 1250;
```

Тогда все сходится, eсли `1250` это стоимость одной единицы `u.ore`.

Comment: И вместо `u.ore-=u.ore;` лучше явно писать `u.ore = 0;`, тогда и намерения ваши будут более ясными)